# Why is my Lambda function called several times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created the following function in Lambda:

```
import time

def handler(event, context):
    print(event['message'])
    time.sleep(120)
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'message': "Got you!"}
```

I changed the timeout of the function to 3 minutes. Now I run it like this:

```
$ aws lambda invoke --payload '{"message":"First"}' --cli-binary-format=raw-in-base64-out --function-name=my_lambda outfile
```

When I go to CloudWatch Logs, I see
[image]

The function is run twice by the runtime.

I know that a function may be called several times when it is called asynchronously, but here it is called synchronously.

However, it doesn't seem to happen when I run it with the flag: `--cli-read-timeout=0`.

Comment: I'd assume the client gives up after 60 seconds as per cli doc on the read timeout and retries. What does the command return at the very end? Is it sill running when the second invoke is happening?

Comment: It says something like "read timeout reached" or something like this.

Comment: Then it’s this behavior. CLI won’t wait long enough and retries. This fails too and you get two invokes and cli error.